# What to replace JdbcTokenStore in Spring Security 5 / Oauth2?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I'm updating an old system to  now updating to Spring 2.6+ and Spring Security 5 / Oauth2 (these should be the new versions exactly) but trying to keep compatibility in a legacy system that uses Spring 1.x and JdbcTokenStore to store and read (bearer) tokens but I couldn't find a replacement for TokenStore object (which doesn't even exist in newer dependencies)

I'm trying to find a replacement for TokenStore / JdbcTokenStore so that I can keep using legacy oauth_access_token table but I could only find relevant code related to JWT and nothing related to TokenStore in newer dependencies. I also tried looking for this migration guide https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide but still not clear what can I do.

What can I do in this case, please?